# Deny or allow the creation of a new record if in the parent object (records) - the field of the picklist type has the status "closed" or "active"

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, master-detail, create-records

I have two objects: Training and Participant with a master-detail relationship (Training (master), Participant (detail)).
When training is "canceled" (Status (Picklist) field selected accordingly) - new participants cannot be added; When the training is active - participants can be added. Is this done with a trigger or is it possible to do without it? Which Salesforce Mechanism is Better?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a validation rule on the Participant object to check if a new Participant is being created (ISNEW()), and if the status of the Training is not active

```
AND (
    ISNEW(),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Training__r.Status__c, "Active"))
)
```